# Which book has the best discussion of DBIx::Class?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I don't know if the [DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class) ORM is substantial enough to justify an entire book on the subject but I'd like to get a recommendation for a book that goes into the details of the DBIx::Class ORM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if you can do much better than the [online documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/).  Between the [introduction](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Intro.pod), [walkthrough example](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Example.pod), and [cookbook](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Cookbook.pod), I think you'll have all you need to get started.  Once you've looked through those, most of what you'll need for working with the ORM can be found in the [ResultSet](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/ResultSet.pm) pod.

If you're really looking for a book, [Jonathan Rockaway's Catalyst](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847190952) has a few chapters on setting up a DBIx-Class model.  Obviously, most of that book is going to be irrelevant unless you're writing a Catalyst web app.

Comment: I think the DBIx::Class chapter of my book is still one of the best resources.  ircxory is a real app with complex data needs, and the book describes it in detail.  I would pick up a used copy, though; $30 is a lot to pay for one relevant chapter :)

Answer (score 2):

There is now also a chapter in the new Catalyst book: [The Definitive Guide to Catalyst](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Definitive-Guide-Catalyst-Maintainable-Applications/dp/1430223650/). I'm also updating and extending my tutorial ([DBIx::Class::Tutorial](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class-Tutorial)) for a [EPO](http://enlightenedperl.org) grant.

Answer (score 1):

[This book by Jess Robinson](https://github.com/castaway/dbix-class-book/blob/master/chapters/00-Preamble.md) is a good introduction to base concepts and advanced principles of DBIx::Class.

I remember that many times, when dealing with unlucky searches I ended up on it and found very useful examples. Worth reading to know about a wide range of tools and concepts that you could dig in the excellent but difficult to search `DBIx::Class` documentation.